# What is the American equivalent of "catch out"?

Tags: word-request, american-english

"Catch out" would be a good addition to my vocabulary, but I understand it's from BrE. What do they say in the US to convey that meaning?

Comment: It's the same thing. It is not BrE. It's just English. You really need to show that it is BrE. Only the cricket term is British, not the regular term. You also should provide a definition and not make us do all the work.

Comment: "“If anyone could have led the charge of content moving to computers, it could have been Viacom. But they got caught out.” - Jonathan Taplin, director of the Annenberg Innovation Lab at the University of Southern California, reported in _USA Today_, June 2016.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133420/discussion-on-question-by-sergey-zolotarev-what-is-the-american-equivalent-of-c).

Comment: This question still does not show any research into US versions of this expression, so I'm leaving it closed for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, let me say that "relevance" is very subjective. AmE is more relevant in some contexts, and BrE is more relevant in other contexts. Neither is inherently more relevant than the other.

As for your actual question, in the U.S. we often simply say "to catch" without "out". For example, a teacher catches a student cheating or a proofreader catches an author's misspelling. One could also say "to find out", e.g., "The student tried to sneak a cell-phone into the exam but got found out."